# condition to be a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

Let us consider two matrices $X$ and $Y$ where both $X$ and $Y$ are $n \times k$ and $X \neq Y$.
It is clear that $X'X$ is a symmetric matrix. What I want to know is whether $X'Y$ is always non symmetric when $Y \neq X$ and its proof when it is true. If not, what condition is required for $Y$ and $X$ to have symmetric $X'Y$?

Comment: $X' Y$ is not always non-symmetric. For example, take $Y$ as the zero matrix.

Comment: Sorry, I assume all the columns of $X$ and $Y$ are non-zero vectors.

Comment: Still can take $X$ any scalar multiple of $n\times n$ identity, $Y$ an arbitrary symmetric matrix.  More generally, take any two symmetric matrices that commute.

Comment: Let's look at an example. For $\pmatrix{1&2\cr3&4\cr}\pmatrix{a&b\cr c&d\cr}$ to be symmetric it is necessary and sufficient that $3a+4c=b+2d$. Not much of a consition, not easy to see how to generalize it for $n\times k$ matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product $X'Y$ may not be symmetric. As far as I know, without further information about the structure of $X$ and $Y$, there is no substantially different method to verify symmetry beyond performing the product and verifying if the resulting matrix is symmetric.

On the other hand, if $X$ is a scalar multiple of $Y$, then $X'Y$ is symmetric. This is only a sufficient condition. However, it becomes a necessary condition when $X$ and $Y$ are non-zero row vectors.

Comment: Many thanks. My understanding is that $X'Y$ is not symmetric in general. However, we cannot rule out for the some rare cases where $X'Y$ becomes symmetric even when there are no special relationship between $X$ and $Y$.  For general$X$ and $Y$, one can only verify after computation of $X'Y$. Am I correct?

Comment: @user0131, as far as I know, your understanding is correct.